# xterm -e - do not close xterm after command

Tags: python, bash, xterm

I had wrote scirpt in python which execute bash command using `system.os("cmd")`. I wouldn't like to have output of bash script on same terminal what I have python script output, so I execute bash command via `xterm -e`. My code is similar to this:

```
# python
import os
os.system("xterm -e 'ls'")
```

This code works but after `ls` end the new terminal disappear. I want to have stay this terminal.

Comment: Your running python script is a process that, when it ends, also closes all forked/execed child processes. It's a wild guess but perhaps prepending nohup will work: `os.system("nohup xterm -e 'ls' >/dev/null &")`. I do not know the technology behind `os.system("cmd")`.

Comment: Sorry, that won't work. I tried it. But Xterm ends itself after a -e "command" call. Try `xterm -hold -e 'ls'`. And combine it with nohup as I said above if you want the python script not to halt on the system call.

Comment: Sorry again ;-). You don't need the nohup; only the & at the end of the command to put the process in the background.

Answer (score 1):

You can let the the window stay until the user presses a key with [`read`](http://linuxcommand.org/wss0110.php):

```
os.system("xterm -e 'ls; read'")
```

or you just run a new terminal of `xterm` which runs until it is closed:

```
os.system("xterm")
```

**Note 1**: The [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system) function seems to block the python script until the external process (xterm in this case) has finished. So you can use it in a loop where each bash window has to be closed before a new one is opened.

**Note 2**: the python documentation suggests to use [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)

Comment: My script run os.system in loop, so I can wait for user press key. After run my script I want to have open 10 xterm with result of bash command, what is importent next bash command can not be run before previous end.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work. I tried it on a Mint linux box.

```
import os
os.system("xterm -hold -e 'ls' &")
```